# Vlookup cells containing dates in date format, text and general format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm vlooking up cells that contain dates, some of which are in date format, others in text format and others in general format. I am trying to `vlookup` the value of the cells as it is shown.

So far, if the format of the cell is date, it returns a number, if the format of the cell is text returns the value correctly and if the value of the cell is date, it returns number, which if I manually turn it to date format, it prints the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` and not in `dd/mm/yyyy` as it is in the sheet that I `vlookup` it from. Is there a code to "screeshot" the value and `vlookup` it exactly as it is shown (as if it is a text).

This is something that I tried. It runs but still it does not solve nothing.

**NEW CODE**

```
lastrow2 = ws3.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim cell As Range
Dim CellText As String
For Each cell In ws3.Range("I2:I" & lastrow2)
    If cell.Text <> cell.Value And Len(cell.Value) <= 255 Then
        CellText = cell.Text
        cell.NumberFormat = "@"
        cell.Value = CellText
    End If
Next cell
```

***EDIT***

Examples of input data (I provide two screeshots to see how the input dates have different formats

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try cell.Text?

Comment: Not really.. I will try to see how that works

Comment: If you update your question with sample of the different types of inputs, we can help you make a "universal" date fixer.

Comment: So do you want *11/07/2018* to mean **November seventh** or **July eleventh** ??

Comment: I want it to be July 11th

Comment: @Gary'sStudent check my new code.. I changed it a lot, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short nacro will look for data in columns **I:J** that can be interpreted as a date and convert it into true dates in format *"dd/mm/yyyy"*:

```
Sub DateFixer()
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet, r As Range, d As Date
    Set ws3 = ActiveSheet

    For Each r In ws3.Range("I:J").Cells.SpecialCells(2)
        arr = Split(r.Text, "/")
        If UBound(arr) = 2 Then
            d = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
            r.Clear
            r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            r.Value = d
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: well that worked perfectly! However, I have a question. In the vlookup, the dates appear correctly. In the source worksheet (where the vlookup looks and takes the dates) the dates still have different formats, as they appear in the menu tab! How is that possible?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas  I do not know.